# Facebook Native ads in recycler view android

Tags: android, facebook, admob, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-audience-network

I am wondering if anyone has tried to integrate facebook audience network native ads in recycler view ??

Is there any simple solution like mopub recycler view adapter https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Native-Ads-with-Recycler-View for facebook audience network native ads ??

Comment: You should edit your question and include a code snippet showing what you already tried in order to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

I create a lib for loading Facebook Native Ad in Adapter.

https://github.com/ldt116/FBNativeAdAdapter

You can check the example

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
FBNativeAdAdapter fbAdapter = FBNativeAdAdapter.Builder.with(PLACEHOLDER_ID, adapter).build();

RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
rv.setAdapter(fbAdapter);
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Any idea or comments are welcome

Comment: Hi, i tried to import the lib but its not working _ Error:(120, 13) Failed to resolve: me.timos.thuanle:fb-native-ad-adapter:latest.version

Comment: Sorry fixed it. May help others -  compile 'me.timos.thuanle:fb-native-ad-adapter:1.3.2'

Comment: I tried to use it but I get various errors (like this one for example: ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@amazonFlavorDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+.). I think you have to update your library to make it compatible with the latest Facebook Native ad library.

Answer (score 4):

I've implement facebook nativead using recylerview. Here what i do:

(1) Define a customized layout to hold native ad

(2) Pre-load native ads in onCreate() through NativeAdsManager

(3) Overwrite onCreateViewHolder() in the adapter to insert ad's view and normal item view:

```
@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    if (i == 4) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_ad, null);
    }
    else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.normal_item, null);
    }
    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}
```

(4) Overwrite onBindViewHolder() in the adapter to bind the native ad data:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    if (i == 4) {
         customViewHolder.adTitleView.setText(nativeAd.getTitle()));
         ...
    }
    else {
        customViewHolder.textView.setText(normalItem.getTitle()));
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you get started.

Comment: how to you implement the registerViewForInteraction for the various Ads?

Comment: The second parameter in onCreateViewHolder() is the viewType and not position. So 'i' in onCreateViewHolder will not be same as 'i' in onBindViewHolder hence leading to  an exception in onBindViewHolder when trying to set values. You have to override getViewType() in your adapter before using this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example from Facebook itself:
[NativeAdRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/fbsamples/audience-network/blob/master/samples/android/AdUnitsSample/AdUnitsSample/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/AdUnitsSample/adapters/NativeAdRecyclerAdapter.java)

```
package com.facebook.samples.AdUnitsSample.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.ads.AdOptionsView;
import com.facebook.ads.MediaView;
import com.facebook.ads.NativeAd;
import com.facebook.ads.NativeAdLayout;
import com.facebook.ads.NativeAdsManager;
import com.facebook.samples.AdUnitsSample.R;
import com.facebook.samples.AdUnitsSample.models.RecyclerPostItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NativeAdRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<RecyclerPostItem> mPostItems;
    private List<NativeAd> mAdItems;
    private NativeAdsManager mNativeAdsManager;
    private Activity mActivity;

    private static final int AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY = 5;
    private static final int POST_TYPE = 0;
    private static final int AD_TYPE = 1;

    public NativeAdRecyclerAdapter(Activity activity,
                                   List<RecyclerPostItem> postItems, NativeAdsManager
            nativeAdsManager) {
        mNativeAdsManager = nativeAdsManager;
        mPostItems = postItems;
        mAdItems = new ArrayList<>();
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
            NativeAdLayout inflatedView = (NativeAdLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.native_ad_unit, parent, false);
            return new AdHolder(inflatedView);
        } else {
            View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout
                    .recycler_post_item, parent, false);
            return new PostHolder(inflatedView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position % AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY == 0 ? AD_TYPE : POST_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == AD_TYPE) {
            NativeAd ad;

            if (mAdItems.size() > position / AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY) {
                ad = mAdItems.get(position / AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY);
            } else {
                ad = mNativeAdsManager.nextNativeAd();
                if (!ad.isAdInvalidated()) {
                    mAdItems.add(ad);
                } else {
                    Log.w(NativeAdRecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "Ad is invalidated!");
                }
            }

            AdHolder adHolder = (AdHolder) holder;
            adHolder.adChoicesContainer.removeAllViews();

            if (ad != null) {

                adHolder.tvAdTitle.setText(ad.getAdvertiserName());
                adHolder.tvAdBody.setText(ad.getAdBodyText());
                adHolder.tvAdSocialContext.setText(ad.getAdSocialContext());
                adHolder.tvAdSponsoredLabel.setText(R.string.sponsored);
                adHolder.btnAdCallToAction.setText(ad.getAdCallToAction());
                adHolder.btnAdCallToAction.setVisibility(
                    ad.hasCallToAction() ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
                AdOptionsView adOptionsView =
                    new AdOptionsView(mActivity, ad, adHolder.nativeAdLayout);
                adHolder.adChoicesContainer.addView(adOptionsView, 0);

                List<View> clickableViews = new ArrayList<>();
                clickableViews.add(adHolder.ivAdIcon);
                clickableViews.add(adHolder.mvAdMedia);
                clickableViews.add(adHolder.btnAdCallToAction);
                ad.registerViewForInteraction(
                        adHolder.nativeAdLayout,
                        adHolder.mvAdMedia,
                        adHolder.ivAdIcon,
                        clickableViews);
            }
        } else {
            PostHolder postHolder = (PostHolder) holder;

            //Calculate where the next postItem index is by subtracting ads we've shown.
            int index = position - (position / AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY) - 1;

            RecyclerPostItem postItem = mPostItems.get(index);
            postHolder.tvPostContent.setText(postItem.getPostContent());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPostItems.size() + mAdItems.size();
    }

    private static class PostHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvPostContent;

        PostHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tvPostContent = view.findViewById(R.id.tvPostContent);
        }
    }

    private static class AdHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        NativeAdLayout nativeAdLayout;
        MediaView mvAdMedia;
        MediaView ivAdIcon;
        TextView tvAdTitle;
        TextView tvAdBody;
        TextView tvAdSocialContext;
        TextView tvAdSponsoredLabel;
        Button btnAdCallToAction;
        LinearLayout adChoicesContainer;

        AdHolder(NativeAdLayout adLayout) {
            super(adLayout);

            nativeAdLayout = adLayout;
            mvAdMedia = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_media);
            tvAdTitle = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_title);
            tvAdBody = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_body);
            tvAdSocialContext = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_social_context);
            tvAdSponsoredLabel = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_sponsored_label);
            btnAdCallToAction = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_call_to_action);
            ivAdIcon = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_icon);
            adChoicesContainer = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.ad_choices_container);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To prevent the first item to be an, insert this in `getItemType()` : `return position % AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY == 0 && position != 0 ? AD_TYPE : POST_TYPE;`