# Facebook Native Ads in RycyclerView android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, facebook-audience-network

I found similar issue [Facebook Native ads in recycler view android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908308/facebook-native-ads-in-recycler-view-android) , but had some problems with integration with Custom Ad.

For the first I tried to describe `NativeAdsManager` :

```
  @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    manager = new NativeAdsManager(getActivity(),    "892769720837476_892772047503910", 5);
    manager.setListener(this);
    manager.loadAds();

    nativeAd = new NativeAd(getActivity(), "892769720837476_892772047503910");
    nativeAd.setAdListener(this);
    nativeAd.loadAd();
...
 }
```

Then I included `Native ad` as a parameter in `RecyclerAdapter` constructor:

```
  adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(foodDataList, getActivity(), nativeAd);
```

In this `Class` I also implement `AdListener` and `NativeAdsManager.Listener` methods:

```
@Override
public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {

}

@Override
public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
}

@Override
public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

}

@Override
public void onAdsLoaded() {

    System.out.println("Loaded in fragment");
    nativeAd = manager.nextNativeAd();
    nativeAd.setAdListener(this);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

@Override
public void onAdError(AdError adError) {

}
```

After that in `RecyclerAdapter`  class :

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
    ...
    case 2:
            AdditionalHolder new_holder = (AdditionalHolder) holder;
            adView = NativeAdView.render(context, nativeAd, NativeAdView.Type.HEIGHT_100);
            new_holder.templateContainer.addView(adView);
            return;

   ...
    public class AdditionalHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected LinearLayout templateContainer;

    public AdditionalHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        templateContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ad_test2);



    }
}
```

After  all of that  my `Fragment` with `RecyclerView` becomes very "luggy" and every time I can see more and more ads items (1 - from the beginning, 2 - after 10 items, 3 - after next 10 and so on).

It's  my first time of using multiple `RecyclerView` `holders`, and find this issue difficult.

Provide you  with gist  of  2 `Classes`

https://gist.github.com/burnix/6af8196ee8acf5c8f94e - `RecyclerAdapter.class`
https://gist.github.com/burnix/53dc2ed7446969b78f07 - `FragmentList.class`

Help me please to solve lugs problem and to place `AudienceNetwork` as it needs to be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this project: https://gist.github.com/burnix/84581959a9c3ebceecf8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours of headache  I solved my problem. 
I needed to change the constructor of `RecyclerView`:

```
  public RecyclerAdapter(List<FoodData> food, Context context, NativeAd  nativeAd, NativeAdsManager manager) {
    this.foodDataList = food;
    this.context = context;
    this.nativeAd = nativeAd;
    this.manager = manager;
}
```

And implement the behavior of Native Ads  in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
  AdditionalHolder new_holder = (AdditionalHolder) holder;
            try {
                new_holder.templateContainer.removeViewInLayout(adView);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            nativeAd = manager.nextNativeAd();
            try {
                adView = NativeAdView.render(context, nativeAd, NativeAdView.Type.HEIGHT_300);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            new_holder.templateContainer.addView(adView);
            new_holder.blank_holder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But it hasn't solved my problem entirely (micro-lags while scrolling), but still it could be useful for someone, I hoped.

Comment: Did you remove this line ``nativeAd = manager.nextNativeAd();`` from the onAdsLoaded in your main activity or did you keep it?

Answer (score 1):

```
       Youur adapter==>

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.LinearLayout;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;

        import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
        import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.GlideDrawable;
        import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
        import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;
        import com.romantic.pictures.hd.love.wallpaper.download.R;
        import com.romantic.pictures.hd.love.wallpaper.download.activity.ROMANTIC_LOVE_WALLPAPER;
        import com.romantic.pictures.hd.love.wallpaper.download.model.ImageStorage;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

        /**
         * Created by abc on 4/11/2018.
         */

        public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

            public final int CONTENT_TYPE = 0;
            public final int AD_TYPE = 1;

            private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
            Activity context;
            ArrayList<ImageStorage> catagorilist;

            public ImageAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ImageStorage> catagorilist, OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener) {
                this.mOnItemClickListener = mOnItemClickListener;
                this.context = context;
                this.catagorilist = catagorilist;
            }


            public interface OnItemClickListener {
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                Log.e("TAG", "getItemViewType position : " + position);
                Log.e("TAG", "getItemViewType position% : " + position % 5);

                if (position % 7 == 0)
                    return AD_TYPE;
                return CONTENT_TYPE;
            }


            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                switch (viewType) {
                    case CONTENT_TYPE:
                        Log.e("TAG", "content type : ");
                        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout2, parent, false);
                        return new MyHolder(view);

                    case AD_TYPE:
                        Log.e("TAG", "ad type : ");
                        View nativeView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_nativead, parent, false);
                        return new NativeAd(nativeView);
                    default:
                        Log.e("TAG", "default : ");
                        LayoutInflater inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout2, parent, false);
                        return new MyHolder(v);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
                holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
                int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
                ImageStorage listitem = catagorilist.get(position);


                switch (viewType) {
                    case CONTENT_TYPE:
                        Log.e("TAG", "bind CONTENT_TYPE : ");
                        final MyHolder menuItemHolder = (MyHolder) holder;


                        //        holder.imagview.setText(listitem.getId());
                /*holder.cat_name.setText(listitem.getName());*/
                        Glide.with(context).load("http://learntodraw.in/ImageApp/new_" + listitem.getCat_imagem()).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                menuItemHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }
                        }).into(menuItemHolder.imagview);
                        Log.e("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: " + "http://learntodraw.in/ImageApp/new_" + listitem.getCat_imagem());
                        Log.e("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: " + position);


                        menuItemHolder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, position);
                            }
                        });


                        break;

                    case AD_TYPE:
                        Log.e("TAG", "bind AD_TYPE : ");
                        final NativeAd nativeHolder = (NativeAd) holder;
                        ROMANTIC_LOVE_WALLPAPER.showNativeVidAd(context, nativeHolder.container);

                        nativeHolder.container_height.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
        //                        int height = nativeHolder.container_height.getHeight();
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = nativeHolder.container.getLayoutParams();
        //                        params.height = height;
                                params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                                nativeHolder.container.setLayoutParams(params);

                              //  nativeHolder.linearlayout_title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                }


            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return catagorilist.size();
            }


            public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                public ImageView imagview;
                public LinearLayout mainLayout;
                public CardView cardview;
                public ProgressBar progressBar;

                public MyHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);


                    imagview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagview);
                    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
                    progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                    cardview = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
                }
            }

            public static class NativeAd extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

                LinearLayout container;
                LinearLayout container_height;
        //        LinearLayout linearlayout_title;

                public NativeAd(View view) {
                    super(view);
                    container = view.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_container);
                    container_height = view.findViewById(R.id.container_height);
                   /* linearlayout_title = view.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_title);*/
                }
            }

        }






public static void showNativeVidAd(final Activity context, final LinearLayout nativeContainer) {

        final NativeAd  nativeAd = new NativeAd(context, context.getString(R.string.fb_test_ad_img) + context.getString(R.string.native_ads3));
//        final NativeAd nativeAd = new NativeAd(context, context.getString(R.string.facebook_native_ad_unit_id));
        nativeAd.setAdListener(new com.facebook.ads.AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError error) {
                // Ad error callback
                Log.e("TAG", "facebook native error : " + error.getErrorMessage());
                nativeContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                // Ad loaded callback
                Log.e("TAG", "facebook native onAdLoaded : ");
                if (nativeAd != null) {
                    nativeAd.unregisterView();
                }

                try {
                    LinearLayout nativeAdContainer = nativeContainer;

                    nativeAdContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // Add the Ad view into the ad container.
                    nativeAdContainer = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_container);
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    // Inflate the Ad view.  The layout referenced should be the one you created in the last step.
                    RelativeLayout adView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_nativead, nativeAdContainer, false);

                    nativeAdContainer.removeAllViews();
                    nativeAdContainer.addView(adView);

                    // Create native UI using the ad metadata.
                    MediaView nativeAdMedia = (MediaView) adView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_media);

                  /*  //TextView nativeAdSocialContext = (TextView) adView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_social_context);
                    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "ProximaNova-Semibold.otf");
                    nativeAdSocialContext.setTypeface(typeface);*/

//                    TextView nativeAdCallToAction = (TextView) adView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_call_to_action);

                    // Set the Text.
//                    nativeAdSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
//                    nativeAdCallToAction.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());

                    // Download and display the ad icon.
                   // NativeAd.Image adIcon = nativeAd.getAdIcon();

                    // Download and display the cover image.
                    nativeAdMedia.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

                    // Add the AdChoices icon
                    LinearLayout adChoicesContainer = (LinearLayout) adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_choices_container);
                    AdChoicesView adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(context, nativeAd, true);
                    adChoicesContainer.addView(adChoicesView);

                    // Register the Title and CTA button to listen for clicks.
                    List<View> clickableViews = new ArrayList<>();
//                    clickableViews.add(nativeAdCallToAction);
                    clickableViews.add(nativeAdMedia);
                    clickableViews.add(adChoicesContainer);
                    nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(nativeAdContainer, clickableViews);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                // Ad clicked callback
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                // Ad impression logged callback
                Log.e("TAG", "facebook native onLoggingImpression");
            }
        });

        // Request an ad
        nativeAd.loadAd(NativeAd.MediaCacheFlag.ALL);
    }
```

Comment: With this example I could get the AppLovin NativeAd running.